# phpMyAdmin Increase Price with specific ID

Tags: phpmyadmin

I Have browsed many questions relating to this similar feed, however nothing specific has helped me yet. So I decided I would create a new question.

Ok I am looking to update prices for products in a table with an increase of **6%**. However, there are only certain ID's that I would like to increase. For example I have almost 2,000 records to update and I want to increase product ID such as 1,2,5,10,24,200,254,289,300, ect. How do I go about doing this please?

I need to increase the table product_variant the productID and its price and final price.

[See spinet of Database table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0zVD.png)

Comment: UPDATE product_variant SET Price=Price+(Price*(6/100)) WHERE productID IN (1,2,5,10,24,200,254,289,300)

Comment: Hi @Ultrazz008 thank you for your speedy reply I really do appreciate your help. This works a charm, however how do I update both Price and Final Price in one SQL statement similar to what you suggested.

Comment: just add comma and set the mutiple update column    UPDATE product_variant SET Price=Price+(Price*(6/100)),Final Price=whatever your value  WHERE productID IN (1,2,5,10,24,200,254,289,300)

Comment: I tried this but error, UPDATE product_variant SET Price=Price+(Price*(6/100)),FinalPrice=FinalPrice+(FinalPrice*(6/100)) value WHERE productID IN (18) @Ultrazz008

Comment: Oops I didnt see that Value* sorry

Comment: no need that value string  that is statement what_ever_your_value . did you understand ?

Comment: try this UPDATE product_variant SET Price=Price+(Price*(6/100)),FinalPrice=FinalPrice+(FinalPric‌​e*(6/100)) WHERE productID IN (18)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my question thanks to @ultrazz008 this worked a charm thank you

**Solved!**

```
UPDATE product_variant SET Price=Price+(Price*(6/100)),FinalPrice=FinalPrice+(FinalPric‌​‌​e*(6/100)) WHERE productID IN (18)
```